# nested list visualised as interactive cycle diagram

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I want to create an interactive [cycle diagram](https://www.google.com/search?q=cycle%20diagram&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeisvQmLLNAhVC1xQKHdLIDPMQ_AUICCgB&biw=1276&bih=739) based on a nested list. The top elements of the list should be in the cycle and the nested list elements I would like to appear when you hover over the first.

I have done quite some googling but could not vind an easy solution. Should I use HTML canvas or just CSS or preferably some framework that could do this easily.

I need some help here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just wanted to expose some data's diagrammatically, right?

If so, you can go with some jquery css controls, because developing such a controls is not at all easiest one. But it can be available from [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/).

Now the community licence is free for their whole products.

Comment: There is actually no data aggregation involved. It is just plain a list that needs to be represented in a cycled form. I could also opt not going for the list and writing div's in HTML to get to the result, but e nested list seemed semantically a beter solution.

Comment: Yes whatever Sharon, According to my experience, its pretty tough to develop the interactive diagrammatic representation of list of data with possible scenarios. Better we can use the third parties controls

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific enough to give any concrete answers but if you are looking for an example of how of how to code a cycle diagram, here's an implementation I just did put together with `d3`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <script src="//labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .d3-tip {
      line-height: 1;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 12px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
    
    .d3-tip:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 1;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    /* Westward tooltips */
    
    .d3-tip.w:after {
      content: "\25B6";
      margin: -4px 0 0 -1px;
      top: 50%;
      left: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data = [{
        label: 'one',
        children: ['all', 'the', 'rain']
      }, {
        label: 'two',
        children: ['fails', 'mainly']
      }, {
        label: 'three',
        children: ['on', 'the', 'plains']
      }, {
        label: 'four',
        children: ['now', 'is', 'the']
      }, {
        label: 'five',
        children: ['time', 'for', 'all']
      }, {
        label: 'seven',
        children: ['good', 'men', 'to']
      }, {
        label: 'eight',
        children: ['come', 'to', 'the']
      }, {
        label: 'nine',
        children: ['aid', 'of their', 'country']
      }],
      width = 500,
      height = 500,
      c = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
      ro = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - (c * .1),
      ri = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - (c * .3),
      a = (Math.PI * 2) / data.length,
      colors = d3.scale.category10();

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .direction('w')
      .html(function(d) {
        return d.children.join(" ")
      });

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(ri)
      .outerRadius(ro);

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500)
      .call(tip);

    svg = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + c + ',' + c + ')')

    var arcs = svg.selectAll('.cycle')
      .data(data);

    var arcsG = arcs.enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'cycle');

    arcsG
      .append("path")
      .attr('class', 'cycle')
      .style('fill', function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
      })
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return "path" + d.label;
      })
      .attr("d", function(d, i) {

        arc.startAngle(a * i);
        arc.endAngle(a * (i + 1));
        d.centroid = arc.centroid();

        return arc();
      })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

    arcsG
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.centroid + ")";
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.label;
      })
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
      .style("pointer-events", "none");

    // draw arrow heads last so they end up on top
    arcs
      .enter()
      .append('polygon')
      .attr("points", function(d, i) {
        var sta = a * i,
          spa = a * (i + 1);
        // determine points for arrowhead
        arrowHead = [Math.cos(spa - Math.PI / 2) * (ri - 15), Math.sin(spa - Math.PI / 2) * (ri - 15)] + ' ';
        arrowHead += [Math.cos(spa - Math.PI / 2) * (ro + 15), Math.sin(spa - Math.PI / 2) * (ro + 15)] + ' ';
        arrowHead += [Math.cos(spa - Math.PI / 2 + ((spa - sta) / 4)) * (ri + (ro - ri) / 2), Math.sin(spa - Math.PI / 2 + ((spa - sta) / 4)) * (ri + (ro - ri) / 2)];

        return arrowHead;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Block [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/1d4b242e86bfde14490ba3ea82261958)